# How to refresh PHP script in MVC without refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to refresh a controller in a MVC website in order to find out if a variable was changed so I can execute a SQL query.

I tried to do it from view file like this:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            $('#show').text(<? $ukaz->process(); ?>);
        }, 1000);
    }
);
```

but it doesn't work. I've been trying to figure it out for hours but unsuccessfully so I thought I could ask here.

Comment: You need to use AJAX. One does not simply call PHP code from JS.

Comment: `$('#show').load('/some/url/that/calls/your/php/script.php');`

Comment: I can't just load the file. It will return php error because it's MVC (OOP) website.

Comment: Do you want to hit a controller function from your view?

Comment: If MVC or OOP stop you from making an AJAX request without a PHP error, I'm afraid you're doing it wrong.

Comment: $container.load('../controllers/SomethingController.php'); returns  Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found in controllers/LikeController.php on line 3

Comment: The URL you call needs to work exactly the same way as your other pages, the way whatever framework you're using is expecting. Calling a controller directly when you're actually using something that uses e.g. an autoloader isn't going to work. Though I'm a little thrown by what framework you could be using if your controllers are available from the web root...

Comment: I'm not using any framework. And I didn't post start of the error message. Is it posible to call function from the PHP script i nead to refresh instead of the PHP file it self?

Answer (score 1):

You need to made ajax call and inside ajax call you can do anything.

On main page you need to define your ajax call like this:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            $('#show').load('ajax.php');
        }, 1000);
    }
);
```

and in your **ajax.php** you need to create PHP function where you will get all your informations what will be changed on each refresh.

You can do also another approach with jQuery [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), [$.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) and [$.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) where you can handle with content inside ajax, use JSON or parse some HTML etc. You can do anything in real time.

Comment: I can't load a php class.

Comment: @Muhaha With an AJAX call you are not directly loading a PHP class.  You are making an HTTP request against an endpoint on your server (likely to be a PHP script in this case).  Within that script, you execute whatever logic you need (i.e. loading classes, calling databases, etc.) and return a result (via output from script) to the calling AJAX client.

Comment: I'm still geting this: Fatal error: Class 'Controller' not found in /web/controllers/SomethingController.php on line 3

Comment: OK I've put json in the controller like this:                                                                                                                            $ret = array();
     $ret['stav'] = $id;
     echo json_encode($ret);                                                                                              But i stil dont know how to get the data from the json.